# RESTful APIs in Django for GETTING information from a server

Tags: python, django, rest, api

Any idea of a RESTful APIs in Django for GETTING information from a server?

What I want to do is fetch the errors from the server into a database.

For example:

The Live server has examplewebsite.com, any thing goes wrong with that website should POST the error, where the Django app GET the errors and insert them into the database.

Comment: @Jeff how do you know that is his question? You added a lot of "meat" to his question. Where did it come from?

Comment: @jrob: From an answer by hkshambesh that was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home), which calls itself a 'mini-framework for Django for creating RESTful APIs.'

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to fetch data over HTTP? If so, what about [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)?